# Angular viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor() inaccurate scroll

Tags: angular

```
this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor('my_div');
```

This code gives different results based on whether the browser is Chrome mobile or Safari mobile

I have tried implementing `this.viewportScroller.setOffset([])` but that doesn't have any affect at all

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add a delay. I think maybe some DOM structure changes were happening before/after the scroll to cause an offset